# Creating .exe or MSI from WinForms C# Project

Tags: c#, winforms, release

I have a completed WinForms C# Project that I would like to finish up by creating a simple MSI to install the program into a specific location on the client computer.

I have watched many tutorial videos and SO threads but can't seem to find an answer.

Is it possible to do with Visual Studio 2013, or do I need 3rd Party software?

Any info or links to help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Installer project was supported by Visual Studio until 2010, but unfortunately Microsoft discontinued.  Since lots of people complained about it, Microsoft released add-ons.

**VS2013:**
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UnniRavindranathan-MSFT.MicrosoftVisualStudio2013InstallerProjects

**VS2015:**
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects

**VS2017 and 2019:**
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects

**VS2022:**
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2022InstallerProjects

Answer (score 0):

Goto Visual Studio Menu/Build/Publish you Project or 
NameofyourFolder\ProjectName\bin\Debug enjoy.

Comment: This does create an .exe I know, already used this, but then when I install it it installs the program to a unknown location, which is why I want the user to choose where to install it to on their desktop.

Comment: You should use Release version for public usage.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

1.] Install this 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UnniRavindranathan-MSFT.MicrosoftVisualStudio2013InstallerProjects

2.] And refer below links

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0v6hmumCFU

http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2014/04/24/visual-studio-2013-installer-projects-ndash-hello-world-installer.aspx

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/568476/Creating-an-MSI-Setup-Package-for-Csharp-Windows

http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-ai-ext-vs.html